# Hourly partitioning a MySQL table based on time field

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields in it.

```
CREATE TABLE log (
 `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `User` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `RcvdDate` date NOT NULL,
 `RcvdTime` time NOT NULL,
 `Act` text NOT NULL,
 `MID` text NOT NULL,
 `S` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `DD` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `QE` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `DP` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `IN` text,
 `SPO` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `NOS` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `RcvdDate` (`RcvdDate`),
 KEY `RcvdTime` (`RcvdTime`),
 UNIQUE KEY `ReceivedAt` (`RcvdTime`,`SP`,`DP`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now I want to create hourly partitions. So there will be 24 partitions in it. The main reason is that my application creates a log table per day and in log table there are around 36000000 records. So make searching faster I want to create the partition per hour. Also apart from partitioning are there any optimization technique?

The data will be searched mostly using Date / Time / user Fields.

Comment: What is `SIP` and `DIP`?

Comment: 3.6 million records in a partition should be manageable with the right indexing and query structures.  Perhaps you should show the queries that you are trying to optimize.

Comment: @Paul - Sorry, It should read S and DP instead of SIP and SIP respectively.

Comment: Is it possible to creation on per hour basis? If yes, how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

with the schema above, it is not possible to partition due to partition's [requirement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html):

> All columns used in the partitioning expression for a partitioned
>   table must be part of every unique key that the table may have

Suppose the table having this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1(
  log_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  user varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY(log_date, user)
);
```

then there are two ways to partition by hour: using [HASH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-hash.html) and [RANGE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html).

**partition by hash:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1(
  log_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  user varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY(log_date, user)
)
PARTITION BY HASH ( HOUR(log_date) ) 
PARTITIONS 24;
```

**partition by range:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1(
  log_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  user varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY(log_date, user)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ( HOUR(LogDate) ) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ( 1 ),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ( 2 ),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ( 3 ),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN ( 4 ),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN ( 5 ),
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN ( 6 ),
    PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN ( 7 ),
    PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN ( 8 ),
    PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN ( 9 ),
    PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN ( 10 ),
    PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN ( 11 ),
    PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN ( 12 ),
    PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN ( 13 ),
    PARTITION p13 VALUES LESS THAN ( 14 ),
    PARTITION p14 VALUES LESS THAN ( 15 ),
    PARTITION p15 VALUES LESS THAN ( 16 ),
    PARTITION p16 VALUES LESS THAN ( 17 ),
    PARTITION p17 VALUES LESS THAN ( 18 ),
    PARTITION p18 VALUES LESS THAN ( 19 ),
    PARTITION p19 VALUES LESS THAN ( 20 ),
    PARTITION p20 VALUES LESS THAN ( 21 ),
    PARTITION p21 VALUES LESS THAN ( 22 ),
    PARTITION p22 VALUES LESS THAN ( 23 ),
    PARTITION p23 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

on inserting with values:

```
INSERT INTO table1(log_date, user) VALUES
('2019-2-4 20:23:', 'user1'),
('2019-2-4 20:33:', 'user1'),
('2019-2-4 20:43:', 'user1'),
('2019-2-4 20:53:', 'user1'),
('2019-2-4 21:23:', 'user1'),
('2019-2-4 21:33:', 'user1');
```

then you can make sure it will fall to correct partition:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 PARTITION(p20);
+---------------------+-------+
| log_date            | user  |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2019-02-04 20:23:00 | user1 |
| 2019-02-04 20:33:00 | user1 |
| 2019-02-04 20:43:00 | user1 |
| 2019-02-04 20:53:00 | user1 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

however tested with mysql 8.0.19, simple select like this will scan whole partition:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE log_date BETWEEN '2019-02-04 20:00' AND '2019-02-04 20:59';
+----+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions                                                                            | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1 | p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,p18,p19,p20,p21,p22,p23 | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 5       | NULL |    4 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

either select should be with operator `log_date = '2019-02-04 20:23'` or it must be performed with `partition(p0)` attached after table name.